# Error localStorage persistence supported only with MobileWeb

Tags: javascript, mobile, titanium, appcelerator

I'm starting with Titanium Appcelerator and I'm following a tutorial book with some examples. 
I'm testing Models Alloy with `localstorage` but when I run the app it returns me an error like this: 
`Error localStorage persistence supported only with MobileWeb`

What can I do to use the local storage in my app??
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

According to the documentation the localStorage adapter is deprecated.  This means you shouldn't use it anymore and learning to use it may be a waste of time.  It appears you are suppose to use properties instead.

"localStorage for HTML5 localStorage on the Mobile Web platform. Deprecated since Alloy 1.5.0. Use the properties adapter instead. You do not need to define the columns object in the config object. If defined, the object is ignored."
http://docs.appcelerator.com/titanium/3.0/#!/guide/Alloy_Sync_Adapters_and_Migrations